# The continuity of $L^2$ gradient on moving domain

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

I post this on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011522/the-continuity-of-l2-gradient-on-moving-domain) too. Sorry for this short cross posting. But I stuck in this problem for a while... I don't know what the right tool should be used to handle the moving domain problem...

Let $I:=(0,1)$ be given. Let $\bar u\in C^\infty(\bar I)$ be given. Define the energy functional, where $x\in I$ is fixed,
$$
T(u,x):=\int_{I\setminus \{x\}}|u'|^2dx+\int_I|u-\bar u|^2dx,\text{ for }u\in H^1(I\setminus \{x\})
$$
and the function $t$: $I\to\mathbb R$ by
$$
t(x):=\inf\{ T(u,x):\,\,u\in H^1(I\setminus \{x\}\}
$$
Hence, $t(x)$ is well defined.

My question: do we have $t(x)$ is continuous? If yes, what the minimum assumption we need to put on $\bar u$. So far I give $\bar u\in C^\infty(\bar I)$, but it would be ideal that $\bar u\in BV(I)$.

Moreover, I am also wondering that if I define 
$$
u_x:=\operatorname{argmin}\{ T(u,x):\,\,u\in H^1(I\setminus \{x\}\}
$$
Then do I have $u_x$ is continuous in $L^1$ sense? i.e., if $x\to x_0$, then $u_x\to u_{x_0}$ in $L^1$.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give some context? What motivated you to study this problem?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu it's a question arising from signal processing. Note that $T(u,x)$ is almost a mumford shah functional. I will try to add some background later.

Comment: In this one-dimensional case, can't you just go ahead and solve the two boundary value problems? This should work at least for the case where $\bar u$ is a characteristic function of some interval and this would at least tell you what you can hope for in the $BV$-case.